# Error 'dict object' has no attribute 'list' while executing ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am facing error while executing below ansible playbook. I don't know what I am missing, in `with_items`

Trying to retrieve disk details using `gather_subset` module and partition each disk that is available in the file system by looping into the `var`
**Error Message:**

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'list'"}
```

**Playbook:**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - name: Collect Disk Information 
    setup:
      gather_subset:
      - hardware

  - name: Print disks Details
    debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys()| list
     
  - name: Create Partition
    parted:
      device: "{{ item }}"
      number: 1
      part_type: 'primary'
      state: present
    with_items: "{{ disks.list[0] }}"
```

**Print disk details** task is printing below

```
TASK [Print disks Details] ***************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys()| list": [
        "xvdf",
        "xvdb",
        "xvdc",
        "xvda"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an issue in your example, you are refering to var *disks*, but I cannot see this is set anywhere in your example.

You should replace your last syntax:

```
- name: Create Partition
  parted:
    device: "{{ item }}"
    number: 1
    part_type: 'primary'
    state: present
with_items: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_devices.keys()}}"
```